# Browseable pages with R Kable

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour with kable?

[image]

I want to make an R Markdown document (HTML output) that I can browse between pages of a table.

Comment: check out the `DT` package

Answer (score 2):

`rmarkdown::paged_table` is probably what you are looking for.